# Django how to pass basic authorization headers in requests?

Tags: python, django, basic-authentication

I'm totally beginner at Django (from a Node/Express background). I need to to make a call to an API that uses basic authorization.

To make requests i'm using the requests module but I don't know where to pass the auth headers. In Axios I normally set the default headers like this:

```js
import axios from 'axios'
const token = `Basic ${Buffer.from(`${process.env.API_USERNAME}:${process.env.API_PASSWORD}`).toString('base64')}`;
axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.API_URL;
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token;
```

My service in Django:

```py
from base64 import b64encode
import requests
import environ
environ.Env.read_env()

endpoint = 'some url'
credentials = f"{env('API_USERNAME')}:{env('API_PASSWORD')}"
encodedCredentials = str(b64encode(credentials.encode("utf-8")), "utf-8")
auth = f'"Authorization": "Basic {encodedCredentials}"'

def get_api_data():
    return requests.get(endpoint).json()
```

How should I pass the headers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If api using token authentication you can use [`headers`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) argument to pass token with request header:

```
return requests.get(endpoint, headers={"Authorization": f"Basic {encodedCredentials}"}).json()
```

Or you can pass login and password directly with [`auth`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication) argument:

```
return requests.get(endpoint, auth=("login", "password")).json()
```